# Nmap recommendations for ICS scanning

Tags: nmap

ICS systems seem to have to be handled with care concerning network load. So my question is if you probably have any suggestions on how to configure nmap to scan as many machines as possible in parallel whilst keeping the load on every single IP to be scanned low.

So what I am basically looking for is a way to configure nmap to execute

`nmap -T2 -p102,502,20000,34962-34964,44818 <target>`

against every host (in a network given) in parallel.

And would using a TCP scan (-sT) be safer for PLCs than using a SYN scan (-sS) since the handshake would be more complete?

Comment: Port scans are to be avoided at all costs afaik, since it might crash the ICS systems, since they run real time OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. In some OT environments, any scan from nmap can cause disruption. So it doesn't matter what the load is. nmap's crafting of the packets can be a problem all on its own.

So, first off, ensure that nmap won't be a problem.

As for parallelising nmap scans: you write a script. Choose your favourite flavour. Scripting help is beyond the scope of this site.

Would a TCP scan be "safer" than a SYN scan? Again, it depends on the PLC. Maybe, maybe not.